# User profile property returning null in display template works in refiners

Tags: search, people-search

I have a question, When I include a custom managed property which I created mapped to user phone(people:phone) and added it to the people hover display template, I tried both 
var has_phone = !$isEmptyString($getItemValue(ctx, "WorkphoneCustom"));
var has_phone = !$isEmptyString(ctx.CurrentItem.WorkPhone);

I was able to get the managed property values in refiners, but the display template is rendering as null. Any suggestions?

When I debugged, I saw that ctx.current item is not loading with the phonenumber in its properties. Do I need to do any additional steps for loading managedproperty(coming from user profile crawled property) into the current item? Any powershell?

Answer (score 0):

So I kept trying to add the managed property to the item_personhoverpanel_copy.html. And it kept failing or showing that the ctx.currentitem doesnot have that value.
But when I added the managed property to the item_person_copy.html, it has started coming up with value.
I guess to add a managed property to hoverpanel display template it needs to be added to the item display template first.
However I have the Work phone property now displaying on the display template.
Also I was creating the result type copy at site level. Once I created a copy of the result type at site collection level, the property sync message started displaying when editing a display template.

`if(has_phone == true) {
                                var encodedVal = Srch.U.getTrimmedProcessedHHXMLString(Srch.U.getMultipleHHXMLNodeValues(hhProps, "Workphone", 5, delimiter), 145);
                                if (Srch.U.e(encodedVal)) { encodedVal = $htmlEncode(Srch.U.getTrimmedString(Srch.U.getUnEncodedMultiValuedResults(ctx.CurrentItem.Workphone, 5, delimiter), 145)) }
                                if (!Srch.U.e(encodedVal)) {
                                    infoAvailable = true;
                                    if(isExpResult == false) {
_#-->

                                        <li id="Workphone">
                                            <div class="ms-srch-hover-subTitle"><h3 class="ms-soften">_#= $htmlEncode(Srch.Res.hp_PeopleItem_Workphone) =#_</h3></div>
                                            <div class="ms-srch-hover-text" id="_#= $htmlEncode(id + HP.ids.peopleWorkphone) =#_">Workphone :
                                                _#= encodedVal =#_
                                            </div>
                                        </li>
<!--#_ 
                                    } 
_#-->
<!--#_ 
                                } 
_#-->
<!--#_

                            }`

'Workphone':'Workphone'

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and it was driving me crazy. The solution is quite simple but not so obvious, just make sure you check-in your new design template after you made your changes. As soon as you've done that, it's all good.